# Fastest way to move unique array elements to the front and slice the array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, pointers, unsafe

I have a function that gets a pointer to a array with size 4 (always) and must slice only the unique elements and return them. This function gets called 100k times a second thats why it needs to be fast and souldn't pressure the GC very much (thats why buffer variable is a pointer - stackalloc).

```
private const int BufferLength = 4;
private static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<int> SliceUnique(int* buffer)
{
   // TODO: move the unique elements to the front
   // and get the last unique index

   return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, lastUniqueIndex + 1);
}

// Example: 
// input: [1, 3, 2, 1]                      | [1, 4, 4, 4]
// output: [1, 3, 2] (order doesn't matter) | [1, 4]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of input and result that should produce. (In particular defining what isn't a unique element).

Comment: @Richard input: [1, 3, 3, 4] -> [1, 4, 3] or [1, 3, 4] (order doesn't matter), input [2323, 4321, 11, 11] -> [2323, 4321, 11]

Comment: Always four elements? What about just a bunch of `if`s? There won't be that many different inputs...

Comment: @Haukinger yes always 4. Maybe ifs with some sort of [Sorting Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) optimized for array with length of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with (back when the question was about array of ints, but I'm sure it can be modified to handle `ReadOnlySpan<int>` (whatever that is...)).
Tested on my computer, average execution time is 195 milliseconds for 1,000,000 arrays (including the creation of the arrays):

```
int[] RemoveDuplicates(int[] array)
{
    bool remove1 = array[1] == array[0];
    bool remove2 = array[2] == array[1] || array[2] == array[0];
    bool remove3 = array[3] == array[2] || array[3] == array[1] || array[3] == array[0];

    if (remove1 && remove2 && remove3)
        return new int[] { array[0] };
    if (remove1 && remove2)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[3] };
    if (remove1 && remove3)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[2] };
    if (remove2 && remove3)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[1] };
    if (remove1)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[2], array[3] };
    if (remove2)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[1], array[3] };
    if (remove3)
        return new int[] { array[0], array[1], array[2] };
    return new int[] { array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3] };
}
```

testing code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long sum = 0;
    var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    var numberOfTimes = 1000 * 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTimes; j++)
        {
            var a = new int[] { j % 2, j % 3, j % 4, j % 5 };
            var r = RemoveDuplicates(a);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        sum += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} => {1}", string.Join(",", a), string.Join(",", r)));
    }
    double avg = sum / 100;
    Console.WriteLine("Average execution time (100 executions) is {0}", avg);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: after optmizing your answer with ReadOnlySpan i have cut the execution time in two and remove unnecessary allocations

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Can you please share how you optimized it?

Comment: @321X ptp have shared his final solution as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139301/3094533) to his own question.

Comment: Ah yes I see! My bad! I had to scroll down ... *doh*

Answer (score 1):

For an array [a,b,c,d]:

```
if (a==b)
    if (b==c)
        if (c==d)
            return (a,1)
        else
            return (a,d,2)
    else
        if (c==d)
            return (a,c,2)
        else
            if (a==d)
                return (a,c,2)
            else
                return (a,c,d,3)
else
    if (b==c)
        if (c==d)
            return (a,b,2)
        else
            if (a==d)
                return (a,b,2)
            else   
                return (a,b,d,3)
    else
        if (c==d)
            if (a==c)
                return (a,b,2)
            else
                return (a,b,c,3)
        else
            if (a==c)
                if (b==d)
                    return (a,b,2)
                else
                    return (a,b,d,3)
            else
                if (b==d)
                    return (a,b,c,3)
                else
                    if (a==d)
                        return (a,b,c,3)
                    else
                        return (a,b,c,d,4)
```

... you get the idea... just written off the top of my head, so better have unit test with all possible inputs :-)

Comment: almost okey it doesn't get all the cases ->                                    example:                                                                                       
expected 3, result: 4, 3_4_3_2
expected 2, result: 4, 4_2_4_2
expected 3, result: 4, 3_4_2_3
expected 3, result: 4, 3_1_4_1
expected 3, result: 4, 1_3_4_1
expected 3, result: 4, 3_4_2_3
expected 3, result: 4, 3_2_1_3
expected 3, result: 4, 2_4_3_2

Answer (score 0):

@ZoharPeled answer - optimized with ReadOnlySpan

```
    private static unsafe ReadOnlySpan<int> SliceUniqueZoharPeledOptimized(int* buffer)
    {
        bool remove1 = buffer[1] == buffer[0];
        bool remove2 = buffer[2] == buffer[1] || buffer[2] == buffer[0];
        bool remove3 = buffer[3] == buffer[2] || buffer[3] == buffer[1] || buffer[3] == buffer[0];

        if (remove1 && remove2 && remove3)
        {
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 1);
        }

        if (remove1 && remove2)
        {
            buffer[1] = buffer[3];
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 2);
        }

        if (remove1 && remove3)
        {
            buffer[1] = buffer[2];
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 2);
        }

        if (remove2 && remove3)
        {
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 2);
        }

        if (remove1)
        {
            buffer[1] = buffer[3];
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 3);
        }

        if (remove2)
        {
            buffer[2] = buffer[3];
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 3);
        }

        if (remove3)
        {
            return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 3);
        }

        return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(buffer, 4);
    }
```